# Java: seemingly simple loop; is this possible?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to make a game in java but have run into what seems like a simple problem. I need some way to use a loop to print out multiple things but not the traditional way. Basically what i need to do is this:

instead of:

```
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
      e.get(i);
 }
```

i need to do this:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
e.get(0);
e.get(1); //but 1 and above can only be there after a number has been increased past 0
e.get(2);
e.get(3);   
e.get(4);
}
```

where changing i would also change how many "e.get()"s you have.

Any ideas?

to clear things up:

this will not work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int l=5;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        for(int o=0;o<l;o++)
        {
            e.get(o);
        }
    }
}
```

but something along the lines of this will:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    e.get(0);
    e.get(1); //but 1 and above can only be there after a number has been increased past 0
    e.get(2);
    e.get(3);
    e.get(4);
}
```

I have tried the nested for-loop but it does not work for my program. 
for my program to work, each "e.get(0);" needs to physically be there.

sorry if im making this unclear, i have been programming for like 6 hours straight and am reaching a wall :/

Comment: Nested loops? Not entirely clear what you need.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Tell me if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: How is this problem "not solved yet" exactly?

Answer (score 2):

```
int num = 5;
for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<num; j++)
        e.get(j);
```

---

### Edit:

Do you mean this?

```
int num = 5;
e.get(0);

for (int i=1; i<num; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<num; j++)
        e.get(j);
```

Comment: each "e.get()" needs to physically be in the code for it to work, and its not necessary to be inside of a for loop.

Comment: Why does each `e.get()` need to be physically in the code? Why are nested `for` loops not OK in this case?

Comment: The code I've posted is equivalent to the code in your original post, so I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        e.get(j);
    }
}
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I would try `e.length;`

```
for(int i=0;i<e.length;i++)
 {
      e.get(i);
 }
```

Comment: The OP doesn't specify that `e` is an array.

Comment: e just stands for example in this case; e.get(i) isnt actually part of my program.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    e.get(0);
    if (i > 0)
        e.get(1); //but 1 and above can only be there after a number has been increased past 0
    if (i > 1)
        e.get(2);
    if (i > 2)
        e.get(3);
    if (i > 3)
        e.get(4);
}
```

That would make certain all of the e.get() calls are in your code, and I believe would call them correctly if I understand what you want (which I probably don't!).